# Не удаётся поставить elinks на Ubuntu 19

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, apt-get

Устанавливаю **elinks/lynx** на Ubuntu 19.10 на VPS, а система выдаёт ошибку

```
sudo apt-get install elinks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elinks
```

Есть возможность исправить данного рода ошибку или, может быть есть альтернативные варианты установки текстового браузера? Спасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y elinks
```

- Links
- Links2
- Elinks
- Lynx
- w3m
- Netrik